# CSS style attribute autocomplete plugin for Sublime Text

Tags: html, css, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I need to get the completions for style attribute in html. For eg:

```
<div style="text-decor...."></div>
```

Is there any plugin available which has the described feature or any other alternative approach ?

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm hearing your question write, `Emmet` is a package that does an awesome job.

Example:

[image]

[Here's a Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdLg-_shyKU) on how to use it here by Nettuts.  And see the [Emmet Documentation](http://docs.emmet.io/) here.  Hope this helps!